# styling google's new recaptcha checkbox?

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I've implemented Googles new recaptcha checkbox like so:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY"><div>
```

When loaded the iframe contents look like this:

```
<div class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-standard">
  ...
</div>
```

[image]

Here are the styles defined for the current look:

```
.rc-anchor-standard {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  color: #000;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this look:

[image]

I've added this to my css file:

```
.rc-anchor-standard {
  background: #ffffff !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

The style never changes...any thoughts why this isn't working?

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: @paul I'm facing the same problem.  Were you able to solve it-If yes, how?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, I want to add my own custom error-messages to the div with the "rc-anchor-alert" class.  I am unable to access it using JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

These styles are located inside a iframe from another domain (google.com), so no chances to change them due to same-domain policy...

You can scale the contents of your div with recaptcha (`<div id="g-recaptcha"` ... )

```
#g-recaptcha {
    transform: scale(1.42);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

First things first, you forgot a semicolon ';' after border,

```
border: 0px !important
```

perhaps that is canceling the white text and border code. I would fix that and see if anything changes.

========================================

If this isn't another typo, this may be why:

You are calling 2 seperate div classes here, but you have them written as a div inside a div.

```
.rc-anchor .rc-anchor-standard {
```

Replace that ^ with this v:

```
.rc-anchor, .rc-anchor-standard {
```

Comment: sorry the missing semi colon was a typo when posting.  Unfortunately the div is loaded via iframe that Google uses after the DOM is ready so I don't have access to it.

Comment: This isn't helpful for getting to a resolution the OQ.